# Grave accent / backtick messes up textediting in gnome 3.24.2

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome

I have a problem with my gnome setup at home (at work everything is fine with the same version 3.24.2).

If I write a text containing a backtick then the behavior of the text is messed up.

If I try to delete the letter that has the grave accent over it, or if I try to delete a *standalone* backtick itself then the backtick sometimes jumps on the letter that is right to the cursor.

If I copy such a text and save it as txt file and open it in an hex editor, then I can see that this backtick is represented as: 0xCC 0x80 instead of 0x60.

It does not happen all the time, and I was not able to tell when and how this happens exactly.

Does anyone know why this might happen and how I could solve that.

Comment: In which applications do you see this behaviour?

Comment: @roaima To get the wrong grave accent, I just had to type in e.g. a textfield in chromium, but I was also able to reproduce in the editor (gedit). The problem was that I had chosen `German (Switzerland, Macintosh)`, because I temporary use an apple keyboard, but this layout seems to be broken, using  `German (Switzerland, no dead keys)` works fine, and only some keys like the `@`  are not correctly mapped, but that's fine. Knowing that it is just the chosen keyboard layout and not a problem with the grave accent in general solves the problem for me.

Comment: Please put that additional problem description in your question, not here in the comments where it can be missed or even accidentally deleted. (The rest is fine in the answer you wrote.) Just remember to accept your own answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem -- it was the wrong keyboard layout.

I did't recognize it at first because most of the keys were correct.